# How read/write into a named pipe in perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, named-pipes

I have a script which have their input/output plugged to named pipes. I try to write something to the first named pipe and to read the result from the second named pipe but nothing happen.

I used open then open2 then sysopen whithout success :

```
sysopen(FH, "/home/Moses/enfr_kiid5/pipe_CGI_Uniform", O_RDWR);
sysopen(FH2, "/home/Moses/enfr_kiid5/pipe_Detoken_CGI", O_RDWR);
print FH "test 4242 test 4242" or die "error print";
```

doesn't made error but didn't work : i can't see trace of the print, the test sentence is not write into the first named pipe and try to read from the second block the process.

Answer (score 2):

Works here.

```
$ mkfifo pipe
$ cat pipe &
$ perl -e 'open my $f, ">", "pipe"; print $f "test\n"'
test
$ rm pipe
```

You don't really need fancy `sysopen` stuff, named pipes are really supposed to behave like regular files, albeit half-duplex.  Which happens to be a difference between your code and mine, worth investigating if you really need this opening pattern.

Comment: The `\n` is an important clue here. :)

Comment: It works without it (the file close event goes "over the pipe"), but it's nicer with it. I wouldn't have expected that to be the OP's problem... but then again who knows.

Comment: Since the OP is presumably not closing the file right away, buffering is probably a concern.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand much of what the OP's intent. I just wrote down an example use of a named pipe in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to unbuffer your output after opening the pipe:

```
sysopen(...);
sysopen(...);

$old=select FH;
$|=1;
select $old;

print FH...
```

And, as [friedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20745/friedo) says, add a carriage return ("\n") to the end of your print statement!

Comment: I have tried to add an \n and to set buffering but nothing more happen.

Comment: Try posting a complete listing of your code and describing your platform/environment and someone may be able to help more easily.