# Run program (and respond to prompts) in background with perl?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, unix, cron

How can I run a program on the command line and pass it input (after it runs) using perl? The goal is to run it on a cron script and design it so that it can't interrupt the user

For example, I'm looking to do this:

```
<run command>
Input required (program prompt): <injected by perl>
<end>
```

Comment: could you add some code? not full understand your question.

Comment: You can create a named pipe and have your script read from it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932143/how-read-write-into-a-named-pipe-in-perl some other process will write commands to named pipe.

Comment: yeah updating now, sorry

Answer (score 2):

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) will handle all of the tough parts for you. You'll have cron execute your perl program and it in turn will spawn the program requiring interaction. Then it's just a matter of coding the appropriate responses to the output the other program produces.

Answer (score 0):

Using pipe?

```
perl xxx.pl | command
```